Reading Global Parameters in ROS2
I am trying to have a global parameter node and a client program that reads the global parameter off of the global parameter node. I am using ROS2 Foxy.
Here is the global parameter node with just one parameter (equal to 2.35):
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class MinimalParam : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MinimalParam()
  : Node("motion_duration_global_param_node")
  {
    this->declare_parameter("current_motion_duration", 2.35);

  }

private:

};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalParam>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

Now, here is the program with the client to read the parameter:
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <std_msgs/msg/string.hpp>
#include <std_msgs/msg/float64.hpp>
#include <rcl_interfaces/srv/get_parameters.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("test_get_global_param");

  rclcpp::Client<rcl_interfaces::srv::GetParameters>::SharedPtr client =
    node->create_client<rcl_interfaces::srv::GetParameters>("motion_duration_global_param_node/get_parameters");

  auto request = std::make_shared<rcl_interfaces::srv::GetParameters::Request>();

  request->names = {"current_motion_duration"};

  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "request->names: %s", request->names);

  while (!client->wait_for_service(1s)) {
    if (!rclcpp::ok()) {
      RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "Interrupted while waiting for the service. Exiting.");
      return 0;
    }
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "service not available, waiting again...");
  }

  auto result = client->async_send_request(request);
  // Wait for the result.
  if (rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(node, result) ==
    rclcpp::FutureReturnCode::SUCCESS)
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "result: %3.3f", result.get()->values);
  } else {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "Failed to call service motion_duration_global_param_node/get_parameters");
  }

  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

When I run the client program, I get this:
ros2 run motion_duration_global_parameter get_global_param_client 
[INFO] [1716489146.680366683] [rclcpp]: request->names: ����U
[INFO] [1716489146.818851917] [rclcpp]: result: 0.000

This is clearly incorrect. Both the parameter name (which should be "current_motion_duration") and the result (which should be 2.35) are wrong.
I don't understand how to define the parameter name. Why is this line wrong?
  request->names = {"current_motion_duration"};
I don't understand how to print the parameter name. Why is this line wrong?
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "request->names: %s", request->names);
I don't understand how to get/print the result. Why is this line wrong?
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "result: %3.3f", result.get()->values);
Any help is appreciated. Thank you for reading.
